# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" in Microsoft Dynamics 365 CRM while adding a new Order Product record

Tags: dynamics-crm, customization, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

Facing this issue and cannot identify the root of this error. Any inputs will be helpful.

When trying to add a new Order Product record associated with Order entity, I am getting the below mentioned **Business Process Error**. When trying with Admin user it does not give any error, but when trying using Standard User it given this error. Please find the related error statement.

P.S: Does this thing has anything do something with Plugin or Business Process Flows?

Thank You.

[image]

[image]

Comment: do you have any Plugin/workflow registered on this or related to this entity?

Comment: Yeah! Got the issue, it is related to a Plugin registered to this entity.

Comment: Cool. I shall add the comment as answer, could you please mark it solved. It will be helpful @RonakLodaya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have an plugin or workflows attached to this entity or related entity to it.

If you check into this direction it will help you analyze deep.

Comment: We can get to the root cause but enabling the Plugin Trace Log in the CRM System by going to _**Advance Settings -> Administration -> System Settings -> Customizations**_ and select **All** in **Plugin Trace Log** field.